# What's the main differences between blue-stack and the indie-stack of remix.run

Tags: remix.run

I see that the blue stack is PostgreSQL-focused, but I don't really understand the decision behind choosing this stack instead of the indie stack.

Why does the blue stack include @remix-run/server-runtime while the indie stack includes the @remix-run/serve package? Furthermore, why do the docs only mention the @remix-run/serve package?

The Remix framework is primarily focused on providing a routing system. Therefore, why does the blue stack include the Express dependency?

Additionally, why does the blue stack have the file server.ts while the indie stack doesn't? And so on...

Answer (score 2):

Remix is not just a routing system. It uses React Router under the hood but provides support for server-side rendering.

Remix allows you to host your app in many environments: Node.js, AWS, Vercel, Cloudflare, etc.

Remix uses adapters to take your host-specific request and convert it to the native Request and hands it off to Remix runtime. Remix then returns a Response object that is returned back to your host adapter which processes it.

`Browser <=> Web Server <=> Adapter <=> Remix <=> App`

For Node.js environments, Remix includes Remix App Server and an Express adapter. RAS is simply an internal Express app that's minimally configured. RAS uses the `@remix-run/serve` package.

The Express template will generate the `server.js` file that gives you full control of your Express entry. If you notice in package.json, you'll see that you will launch your Express server via `node server.js`.

The Indie and Blues stacks were meant to showcase how to build the same app using different backends. Indie uses RAS and SQLite, whereas Blues uses Express and Postgres. The Grunge stack even uses AWS and Dynamo DB.

This will provide more technical information of how it all works.
https://remix.run/docs/en/1.17.1/pages/technical-explanation

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll dive into it. I guess you meant this in the blue-stack package.json:     "build:server": "esbuild --platform=node --format=cjs ./server.ts --outdir=build --bundle",
I guess it was a good informative answer but, I'm not sure it is answering all my questions, I stayed a little bit confused. I Looked for a direct answers, specifically about the stacks focus and less about the remix focus. 
Anyway it seems that you know remix good, so I have another question about the answer, if I use the express do I get a full control on the routing system of remix?